# Django Correct Date / Time not PC date/time

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

Is there a way to get the exact date/time from the web rather than taking the PC date/time?

I am creating a website where the answer is time relevant. But i don't want someone cheating by putting their pc clock back. When i do:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
```

or

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

I still get whatever time my pc is set to.
Is there a way to get the correct date/time.

Comment: The website won't be hosted on the user computer so `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` will return the hosting server time and cannot be tampered with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.today()` takes its time information from the server your application is running on. If you currently run your application with `python manage.py localhost:8000`, the server is your local PC. In this scenario, you can tamper with the time setting of your PC and see different results.
But in production environment, your hosting server will provide the time information. Unless you have a security issue, no unauthorized user should be able to change that.